# Joining strings in FrameLabel

Tags: plotting, string-manipulation, formatting, text

I want the $ x $-axis of this plot to be $ \tau/\alpha_e $ without the "+", but I'm unable to do this without *Mathematica* putting the $ \alpha_e $ to the front of the string.

```
ListPlot[info, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> ({"Time [" Subscript[\[Tau], e] + "/t ]", "MSD [\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(nm\), \(2\)]\)]"}) ]
```

[image]

Comment: I know the question isn't exactly the same but answers cover many approaches to the problem you have.

Answer (score 1):

In Wolfram, `Plus (+)` has no such functionality to concatenate two strings like that in Python. If you must find a counterpart, it should be `StringJoin (<>)`.

However, one can directly typeset in Wolfram codes (which is seen more clearly in the figure below):

```
info = Range[8, 14];

ListPlot[info, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> ({"Time [\[Tau]/\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Alpha]\), \\(e\)]\)]", "MSD [\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(nm\), \(2\)]\)]"})]
```

[image]

Though there is some confusion in the exact letters being used, the format is the same.

---

**Update**

I realized that the stack exchange code environment cannot reflect how the typesetting is accomplished, so I made the image posted include the part of codes. But it seems not enough. It still might lead to the situation that the codes posted above let people think it somewhat troublesome to type.

Actually, it is not, as long as one knows some typesetting shortcuts in a *Mathematica* notebook. For example, <kbd>Esc</kbd> + `t` + <kbd>Esc</kbd> gives one a $ \tau $ and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + `-`/`6` allows one to type a sub/superscript, etc. For more, please check this page [Mathematical Typesetting](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/MathematicalTypesetting.html).

Comment: For those, who like me, don't like messing with low-level box forms, I suggest writing the frame label as `{Row[{"Time τ/", Subscript[α, e], "]"}], Row[{"MSD [", nm^2, "]"}]}]`

Comment: @m_goldberg Thx for your comment! I don't like that either. And in fact I did not directly use low-level box forms at all.  I will elaborate more on typesetting in update.